# Make one more dependency injection inside already dependency injection class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nlog

I write console app on .net core and want to add Nlog into classes. I add dependency injection in program class

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

   try
   {
      var configuration = GetConfiguration("app.config");
      var serviceProvider = BuildDI(configuration);

      using (serviceProvider as IDisposable)
      {
         var tcpController = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TcpController>();
         var median = await tcpController.GetMedian();

         Console.WriteLine(median.ToString());
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      logger.Error(ex);
      throw;
   }
   finally
   {
      LogManager.Shutdown();
   }   
}
```

I generate `ServiceProvider` in this method

```
private static IServiceProvider BuildDI(IConfiguration config)
{
   return new ServiceCollection()
      .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)
      .AddSingleton<TcpController>()
      .AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
      {
         loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
         loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
         loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
      })
      .BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

In `private static IConfiguration GetConfiguration(string configName)` all logic to generate configuration object. I guess we don't need this code for this question.

In `TcpController` i got `private TcpRepository _tcpRepository { get; }` field that create in constructor.

```
public TcpController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<TcpController> logger)
{
   this._configuration = configuration;
   this._logger = logger;
   this._tcpRepository = new TcpRepository(configuration);
}
```

I want to use it field like Transient. I must in `TcpController` repeat method `private static IServiceProvider BuildDI(IConfiguration config)` or in c# we have another way to make this?

Comment: You can add `.AddTransient<TcpRepository>()` to your existing `BuildDi()` method and a reference to `TcpRepository` inside of the `TcpController` constructor like you did with `IConfiguration` and `ILogger`. This will automatically inject an object of type `TcpRepository` inside of your `TcpController` constructor. But be aware that because you registered `TcpController` as `Singleton` you will always operate on the same object of `TcpRepository` despite it being registered as *Transient*. Because it only gets requested once (while creating `TcpController`).

Comment: So i need to make `TcpController` Transient too? Or is it not necessary and the `TcpRepository` will still work as the same object to be registered?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing inside these classes. If you are for example accessing resources which can only be accessed by one at a time (for example opening a TCP listener at a given port) you can not just switch from Singleton to Transient. Same goes for classes which save values in class variables. Do you want to have each requested instance to have the same values or each its own, therefore you use Singleton or Transient.